# Sharepoint Item Workflow always sets Modified By to the Item Creator?

Tags: workflow

I have a custom list with a SP Designer 2013 workflow on it - the flow emails individuals in list fields whenever the list item is changed by anyone. The flow works fine, but the list item is displaying odd behaviour.

No matter who edits an appended multiple text field in the Item, the workflow creates another version of the item and changes the author of the last change to the item creator... even though the time stamps are correct, the Last Modified person is always the Creator! Even though the creator didn’t do the edit.

Is this something that Workflow is doing, can anyone advise where I might have gone wrong?